# Svelte + Rollup can't find Typescript file in Yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript, svelte, rollup, yarn-workspaces

How can I make rollup in the folder "frontend" include a file located in the folder "common"?

```
- root
| - package.json
| - frontend
  | - index.svelte
  | - rollup.config.js
  | - package.json
| - backend
  | - index.ts
  | - package.json
| - common
  | - status.ts 
  | - package.json
```

root/package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "workspaces": [
        "backend",
        "common",
        "frontend"
    ]
}
```

root/frontend/package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project-frontend",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
     ...
     "my-project-common": "^0.1.3",
  }
}
```

root/common/package.json

```
{
    "name": "my-project-common",
    "version": "0.1.4"
}
```

root/common/status.ts

```
export const StatusLabel = {
    CREATED: 'CREATED',
    QUEUED: 'QUEUED',
    RUNNING: 'RUNNING',
    FINNISHED: 'FINNISHED'
}
```

root/frontend/index.svelte

```
 import { StatusLabel } from "my-project-common/status";
```

this returns the error message when building

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
my-project-common/status (imported by index.svelte)
```

Comment: Did you try going to that link in the error? https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency it outlines how to import (it needs to be relative) `import { StatusLabel } from '../common/status'`. I don't think this has anything to do with the monorepo workspaces or package.json. Also, why not make `StatusLabel` an `enum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in the error takes you to a page that says:

> Rollup will only resolve relative module IDs by default

So I would make that import relative like:

```
import { StatusLabel } from '../common/status'
```

Answer (score 0):

As the example docs show from here: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency

```
/ input
// src/main.js (entry point)
import x from '../external.js';
import './nested/nested.js';
console.log(x);
```

Link to it relatively

```
import { StatusLabel } from './common/status'
```